# eclipse odbc Could not find symbol in index

Tags: unixodbc

When I try to click ODBC functions (like, SQLExecDirectW, SQLBindCol and so on), I get the below message. I am currently using Eclipse on Ubuntu.

Example:

Could not find symbol 'SQLExecDirectW' in index.

Can you please let me know how do I configure the eclipse to ensure that details about the function could be known.

Thanks a lor for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution. Though I had the library included in the eclipse project it was not properly referenced.